# regex code issues in C

Tags: c, regex

Every time I run this code it tells me that status is equal to 17 and I have no idea why

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main () {

        char *word[100];
        char *exp[100];
        regex_t w;
        int status;
        printf("Test Expression: ");
        fgets(word,100,stdin);
        word[strlen(word)-1] = '\0';
        status = regcomp(&w,word,REG_EXTENDED|REG_NOSUB);
        printf("Validity of regex, if 0 than it matches: %d\n",status);
        if (status) return 1;
        while (1) {
            printf("Test String: ");
            fgets(exp,100,stdin);
            exp[strlen(exp)-1] = '\0';
            if (strlen(exp) < 1)
            break;
            status = regexec(&w,exp,(size_t)0,NULL,0);
            printf("Matched:  %d\n",status);
            printf("%d\n", status);
            }
        return 0;
        }
```

I think it might have something to do with string length but when I put something simple in the user input line like "d" it still says 17

Comment: `exp[strlen(exp)-1] = '\0';` what? Isn't this redundant? I mean, if `strlen` returns a correct result, `\0` should be there already, no?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca that'll be stripping off the EOL character as `fgets` includes it in the read in string

Comment: `char *word[100];` ==> `char word[100];`

Comment: @ChrisTurner ah, good to know, in that case, shouldn't it be `-2`? Supposing `exp` is "hi" followed by a EOL, `strlen(exp)` would return 3, and `exp[3]` is already `\0`, or am I missing something?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca `exp[3]` is the 4th character, so the 3rd (`exp[2]`) is the EOL. But really a more reliable way is to use something like `strpbrk` to find "\n\r" and replace that (if it finds anything) with a `\0`

Comment: why does display 17 again?

Comment: Check out `regerror()` for error description

Comment: @ChrisTurner oops, my bad. Mild brainfart

Comment: BTW, `char *exp[100];` ==> `char exp[100];` too

Comment: very surprised there aren't pages of warnings from the incorrect type for word & exp

Comment: when it doesn't match it still displays 17